# Customizing clickable area on a Marker in Google Maps v2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am currently using Google Maps v2 API for Android and doing some custom overlays. 
For starters, I create a custom bitmap that is quite a big larger than the standard "marker".

I know that using an older Maps API, you can create a custom overlayitem which controls the click-able area, but it must also be possible on the newer Maps API.  I simply want my custom marker's click-able area to be the same as the custom bitmap icon I am setting it to. I have read over the examples and documentation and couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

(Here is the doc I was reading)

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_a_marker
```

Comment: could you please explain what's the problem? what is the current state?

Comment: As mentioned, I am using a custom icon that is larger than the predefined icon size. It is currently only click-able within the same area as the predefined marker google uses. I would like to to be clickable around the whole icon I am using.

Comment: do you mind to show how you are setting the icon, because I use predefined icon for my markers to and I don't experience this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed. A bug in the library.

I have created a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5368

**Edit:**

This has been fixed recently in the library and should work correctly now.

Comment: Can you please elaborate which version of the google maps API are you using? I can still reproduce this problem on google maps api v2 on Android 4.4.1.

Comment: It's a laugh that this issue is *still* happening https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822967