# Big clickable marker Google android maps api v2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am using the Google android maps api v2, and have to put a tall marker on it (way taller than the default size). The issue is when I put a tall marker, only the bottom half of it is clickable and not the whole marker.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: post the image of tall maker..!

Comment: http://vector.me/files/images/1/6/160887/maidis_vertical_striped_hot_air_balloons_clip_art.jpg

Something like this but not exactly, the point is it has to be taller. I used to take care of this using overlays in the old api. No clue how to do this in the new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the library.

You may want to star the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5368

Also see this: [Customizing clickable area on a Marker in Google Maps v2 for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856677/customizing-clickable-area-on-a-marker-in-google-maps-v2-for-android)

**Edit:**

This has been fixed recently in the library and should work correctly now.

Comment: Thanks a ton, hope they fix it soon.