# Android Google Maps v2: customized marker with large click area

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

Related: [Customizing clickable area on a Marker in Google Maps v2 for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856677/customizing-clickable-area-on-a-marker-in-google-maps-v2-for-android)

I have a number of icons inside an ArrayList, which are all custom icons with a drawable. The problem I have is that the clickable area is that of the default marker. I need to customize this clickable area to the same size of the default marker.

Here is my code to generate a set of markers on the map:

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
for (Icon iconItem: icons) {
  //Scale icon
  int markerSize = 90;

  Bitmap iconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), iconItem.resourceInt);
  Bitmap scaledIconBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(iconBitmap, markerSize, markerSize, false);
  options.position(iconItem.location).title(iconItem.type);
  Marker newMarker = gMap.addMarker(options);
  newMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(scaledIconBitmap));

}
```